# Change of style in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Following is mwe of what I'm doing. I want to get a couple of things.

1. Instead of bold **1**, **2**, I need it to be replaced by **Chapter
   1** and **Chapter 2** respectively, followed by the name.
2. I want the References appeared in the table of contents, separately not under a Chapter, with the heading **References**.

Thank you for any suggestions.

> ```
> \documentclass[11 pt]{article}
>
> \usepackage{amsmath, mathrsfs}
> \usepackage{amssymb}
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[english]{babel}
> \usepackage{blindtext}  
>
> \linespread{1.4}
> \pagestyle{myheadings}    
>
> \title{This is the title}
> \author{Author A and Author B}
> \date{}
> \begin{document}
> \let\conjugatet\overline
> \maketitle
>
> \tableofcontents
>
>
> \section{This is section 1}
> \subsection{This is a subsection}
>
> \section{This is section 2}
> \subsection{This is a subsection}
>
>
> \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
> \bibliography{References}{}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: Pardon me, but why do you load `blindtext` if you don't use it?

Comment: @Bernard, I am USING it. I just got rid of all the packages for the mwe.

Comment: Another point: in the article class there's no chapter. If you really want chapters, you should use `report` or `book`.

Comment: @Bernard, my bad. I changed it to report. Still I don't get "Chapter 1" (say), just a bold one, with the chapter name.

Comment: Use, for instance,  `titletoc`.

Comment: The 'MWE' still has `article` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, pardon me. I still couldn't get it work with the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tocloft` provides the means to add some prefix to chapter number, say, `Chapter`, with `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{...}`. However, this would overprint the chapter number, so the `\cftchapnumwidth` has to be increased accordingly.

For adding the Bibliography to the ToC use `\usepackage{tocbibind}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot]{tocbibind}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{40pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\textbf{\chaptername}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}


%\linespread{1.4}
\pagestyle{myheadings}



\title{This is the title}
\author{Author A and Author B}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cite{Lam94}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\section{This is section 1}
\subsection{This is a subsection}


\section{This is section 2}
\subsection{This is a subsection}

\chapter{Foobar}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to change the heading "Bibliography" to say, "References" ?

Comment: @Fib1123: `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}` should work

Comment: @Fib1123: You have to use the change after `\begin{document}` or wrap it in `\AtBeginDocument`, I have edited the code.