# Chapter heading in upper case letters

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

With reference to my previous question: [Change of style in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419997/change-of-style-in-the-table-of-contents/420016#420016)

How to make this to get what I stated in the title. For eg. **CHAPTER 1, CHAPTER 2** etc. even in the table of contents and at the beginning of the Chapter itself. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `\chaptername` to be `\MakeUppercase{\chapoldname}` and write the change to the ToC itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot]{tocbibind}


\let\chapnameold\chaptername


\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{65pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\textbf{\chaptername}~}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\chaptername}{\MakeUppercase{\protect\chapnameold}}}
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\MakeUppercase{\chapnameold}}
}
\makeatother


%\linespread{1.4}
\pagestyle{myheadings}



\title{This is the title}
\author{Author A and Author B}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cite{Lam94}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\section{This is section 1}
\subsection{This is a subsection}


\section{This is section 2}
\subsection{This is a subsection}

\chapter{Foobar}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I try to improve this code later one to make it more 'condense'

Comment: Thank you. When I compile the code, there's an error comes "Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cftchapnumwidth 
                            
l.25 \addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{65pt} "

Comment: @Fib1123: Works for me out of the box, otherwise I would not have posted this answer.